# Select from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like below:

```
uid nid     points  date                        reason
36  116     2       2012-08-28 11:52:12         session
31  110     2       2012-08-23 15:47:47         session
36  115     2       2012-08-27 11:52:48         session
```

as u can see uid is not unique, it can be repeated. What i need is to select sum of points for every id between date(30 days before). **For example: sum of uid36 = to 4.**
What i have tried:

```
$start_time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $today["mon"], ($today["mday"] - 30), $today["year"]);//30 days before
$end_time = time();
$query = db_query("SELECT uid,sum(points), date FROM users_history WHERE date BETWEEN '$start_time' AND '$end_time'");
```

but how to select for every id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY uid`, and `date` is meanless in your query if you are using aggregate function `SUM`.

```
SELECT uid, SUM(points) 
FROM users_history 
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 day) AND NOW() 
GROUP BY uid
```

And if there is no future date, then you only need

```
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 day)
```

Comment: Also beware that `$start_time` and `$end_time` will either need to be passed through [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) or else formatted as suitable literals for MySQL (e.g. using [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).

Answer (score 1):

for that you need to group your uid.
SELECT uid,sum(points), date FROM users_history WHERE date BETWEEN '$start_time' AND '$end_time'" group by uid;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uid, SUM(points) FROM users_history WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW() GROUP BY uid
```